# How to create user registration form and search them in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to develop a small module for my client's job portal site which is as follows.

Functionality that is required:
1. A user registration form with functionality to upload CV/Docs in the form.
2. User details to be stored in database and to be shown in wordpress backend to the admin.
3. After registration mail should be sended to both user and admin about registration.
4. In frontend there will be a search box to search users that got registered.
5. 3 type of queries for search. a) Search by experience. b) Search by location c) Search by Field e.g(Web Design, Web Developer etc).

I am confused how to make this thing done. If I am using some user registration plugin it is not providing functionality to store the docs. Can anyone please guide me how to develop this functionality

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, create your own form for registration, on submit of the form, create user using [wp_create_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) function. Basic details of users (i.e. username, email and password) will be saved in users table.
All other custom fields you need to save as user_meta using [add_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) function. This way you can create your own user registration form.

Now, regarding search functionality, you can search users using [WP_User_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) method. And based on the search field, you need to pass respective meta_query in this function as below:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'experience',
                'value'   => array( 0, 5 ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'location',
                'value'   => $location,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'Field',
                'value'   => $field,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```